# In Numbers can a chart follow a table's increasing range?

Tags: applescript, numbers

I'm growing a table and also have a chart associated with it but when I add columns I have to go back to the chart and "edit data references". When I was growing the chart from right to left, I didn't have this issue. The chart would continue to grow because I was adding rows within the range. Wondering if this can be automated or handled differently.

This is the way I was doing it and graph didn't need to be edited.

```
tell application "Numbers"
    tell the table 1 of sheet 1 of document "The Doc"
        delay 1
        add column before the range "E1:E2"
        set the value of cell "E1" to time string of (current date)
        repeat with i from 2 to the count of cells of column "E"
            set the value of cell i of column "E" to (the value of cell i of column "C")
        end repeat

    end tell
end tell
```

This is the way I'm doing it now but I have to always edit the data references.

```
tell application "Numbers"
    activate
    tell the table 1 of sheet 1 of document "The Doc"
        set column count to column count + 1
        set myLastColumn to column count
        set the value of cell 1 of column myLastColumn to time string of (current date)
        repeat with i from 2 to the count of cells of column "A"
            set the value of cell i of column myLastColumn of rows to (the value of cell i of column "D")
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Maybe the easiest solution is to create an extra column that won't get data and add column before that so that I increase table size from within.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a better way but this is working.

```
tell application "Numbers"
    tell the table 1 of sheet 1 of document "The Doc"
        set myColumn to column count
        add column before the column column count
        set the value of cell 1 of column myColumn to time string of (current date)
        
        repeat with i from 2 to the count of cells of column "A"
            set the value of cell i of column myColumn of rows to (the value of cell i of column "D")
        end repeat
        
    end tell
end tell
```